# AWS CodeBuild doesn't fail when tests fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, automated-tests

I'm using AWS Codebuild to run the automated tests. However, regardless of the test results, CodeBuild always indicates success.

Even CodeBuild indicating success, when checking the logs, I identified that several tests are failing.

How to make CodeBuild also fail when tests fail?

Thank you for your help.

This is my buildspec:

```
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto11
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Nothing to do in the pre_build phase...
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - mvn test
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
```

Comment: CodeBuild would fail the build when a step (`mvn test` in this case) returns a non-0 code. Your maven POM is probably set up to ignore test failures.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to false

`<testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>`

Comment: xml, in buildspec... where???

Comment: @cosbor11 probably in the pom.xml of maven, but I'm not sure.